# Do not create sub-objects in django

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a model representing a `Status` - and have a foreign key to `Status` from an `Object` model. I want to be able to create new objects, but do not want to allow the possibility of creating any more `Status` entries (there are a set of 5 pre-defined ones that are migrated into the database). I believe I have figured out how to structure serializers in such a way as to only re-use existing `Status` entries, but I'm not sure if it is the best way to go about doing something like this...

Some Simplified Code:

```
class StatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields = ('name',)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.name

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return {
            'name': data
        }


class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    status = StatusSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('obj_name', 'status',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # We do not want to create new statuses - only use existing ones
        status = Status.objects.get(name=self.initial_data['status'])
        return Object.objects.create(status=status, **validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        instance.obj_name = validated_data.get('obj_name', instance.obj_name)

        # We do not want to create new statuses - only use existing ones
        instance.status = Status.objects.get(name=self.initial_data['status']) if 'status' in self.initial_data else instance.status

        return instance
```

As seen above, I also flatten out the `Status` object when it is displayed - e.g. I turn the following

```
{
    'obj_name': 'ObjectName',
    'status': {
        'name': 'StatusName'
    }
}
```

Into this

```
{
    'obj_name': 'ObjectName',
    'status': 'StatusName'
}
```

This seems to work fine -- however **I am not sure how to handle cases where a user of the API gives me an invalid `Status` name.** Right now, the api would bubble up a `Status.DoesNotExist` exception from one of the `Status.objects.get(...)` requests - should I just catch that and re-raise as something the serializer/view would expect?

Thanks!

Edit: Realized my question wasnt exactly clear...

1. Is the above a good way to prohibit creation of `Status` objects - and enforce that any `Object` created will use one of those statuses?
2. What is the best way to handle the case where a user attempts to create an `Object` with an invalid `Status` name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `validate` method in the `ObjectSerializer`.

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    status = StatusSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('obj_name', 'status',)

    def validate(self, attrs):
         validated_data = super().validate(attrs)
         status = self.initial_data.get('status')
         # Here assuming that None is not the valid value for status
         if status is not None:
             status_obj = Status.objects.filter(name=status)
             if not status_obj:
                 raise serializer.ValidationError('Invalid Status')
             status_obj = status_obj[0]
             validated_data['status'] = status_obj
        return validated_data

    # Nothing special to be done in create/update since we are sending data
    # in validated_data which will directly sent to the instance.

    # def create(self, validated_data):
        # We do not want to create new statuses - only use existing ones
        # status = Status.objects.get(name=self.initial_data['status'])
        #return Object.objects.create(status=status, **validated_data)

    #def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # instance.obj_name = validated_data.get('obj_name', instance.obj_name)

        # We do not want to create new statuses - only use existing ones
        # instance.status = Status.objects.get(name=self.initial_data['status']) if 'status' in self.initial_data else instance.status

        # return instance
```

And if you can use different keys for write and read `status`, then you can modify `ObjectSerializer` like this:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializer.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Status.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    status_data = StatusSerializer(read_only=True, source='status')

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('obj_name', 'status', 'status_data')
```

In this case, if you pass `{'obj_name': 'ObjectName', 'status': 'StatusName'}` data to serializer, the serializer will first check for the `StatusName` value in the `name` field of the provided queryset (In this case we are using `all`) and if not valid raises `ValidationError`. If valid, then saves the `status` in the field of the instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Not quite a fan of your second code block - its a bit confusing that Objects are created using the `'status': 'status_name'` field and then are displayed using the `'status_data': 'status_name'` field

Comment: @wKavey I agree that for this particular case, multiple keys might not be a good idea but generally I prefer multi key approach because it removes overhead of custom validation and also frontend require to send only ids rather than sending array of objects every time.